# Grails Caching Plugin and Scaling

Tags: grails, caching, scalability

We're using Grails without a datasource for our front-end and we're going to need to cache some data that we fetch via webservices. I've started investigating the [cache plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/guide/index.html) and it works great. My question is, is it possible to use this plugin in a distributed environment so it is shared between instances? Or do I need to use a different plugin / library for this; echache for example?

Again, this app is not going to use Domains at all, and the Hibernate plugin has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/guide/usage.html) for the plugin you will see the following:

> This 'core' cache plugin uses an in-memory implementation where the
>   caches and cache manager are backed by a thread-safe
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap. This is fine for testing and
>   possibly for low-traffic sites, but you should consider using one of
>   the extension plugins if you need clustering, disk storage,
>   persistence between restarts, and more configurability of features
>   like time-to-live, maximum cache size, etc.

So, in your case you will need to look at using one of the additional plugins such as [ehcache](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-ehcache), [redis](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-redis), or [gemfire](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-gemfire) to enable distribution of the cache across multiple instances of your application (unless you go with Terracotta).